# Raise an event or override a method when the user logs out in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to do something when the user logs out. I have used ASP.NET Forms Authentication.

What should I override or implement?

I have an ASP.NET login control and I want to empty the basket-viewer when the customer logs out of the system.

Comment: Do you abandon session when the user logs out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle the event in `Global::Application_Logout`.

Comment: Are you sure this event exists? I don't see it in global.asax documentation or otherwise.,

Comment: That's disturbing, I wasn't able to find one either! I don't do any ASP.NET Web Forms programming these days, so I don't have a sample app to look at. In lieu of that, I'd look at the `FormsAuthentication.SignOut()` method.

Answer (score 0):

One common approach is program the task you want in the global.asax file. You have the event Session_End that will occur when you logout with forms authentication. Other would do the task on the logout click event. The latter is very NOT recommended, though, because that will leave your tasks undone if the user times out the session (i.e. closing browser).